# Advise on what language or IDE to use for this project

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, mediacenter

I wish to create a media center program to run on a windows based system.

I am a bit lost as to which language would be best for this situation so i am hoping for a little bit of advise on the subject.

I want the program to be similar to XBMC (I don't want to use XBMC because i want to be able to modify the program to do what i want at my will).

I have already created one with windows forms in vb.net which functions really well but i do not like the limitations on the gui (true transparency and lack of transitions are the main ones)

I have tried WPF but i just don't understand it at all, seems really complicated but it seems like what i need to start looking into..

So i need to know if WPF would be my best option? or is there something else that offers the functionality of a vb.net windows form but also offers the ability to create a visually stunning gui.

also is everything that can be done with a vb.net form be done in WPF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should not only think about programming language but also about a component-library (like [DevExpress](http://www.devexpress.com/)) Standard Winform-Controlls (and also WPF) are limited, so extra components can maybe give you a better base. In this case you can go on to use vb.net (or you may think about c#).

Comment: DevExpress looks very interesting, i might give it a go, thanks.
I am guessing a "Component Library" are controls that are more customizable?

Comment: More components, more customizable, more possibilities and (often) more complexity ;-)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, WPF is not complicated but it's definitely different, if you used to implement applications in Winforms. But IMHO it's the much better framework to implement applications, since it has more possibilities to design controls etc.
If you're really want to learn WPF you should get a look into [MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) as well. It provides a good structured way of implementing such applications.
There are also some frameworks created by others to provide a good base for implementing MVVM applications. So you don't need to reinvent the wheel. They are easy to find.

As good tool for WPF development (only for the design part) I recommend MS Blend although it has a steep learning curve. Once gotten familiar with it you will be able to create easily really fancy GUIs.

Since WPF is included in the .Net framework you can use VB.Net without having disadvantages. I would prefer C# but that's totally up to your gusto.

**Edit**

I missunderstood the last part. Yes you can provide any functionality in WPF as in Winforms. (I guess that was meant by *VB.net form*.)

Comment: Ah yes, Winform, sorry i couldn't think of what they were called.